# SQL query for summing from one table into another

Tags: mysql, join, phpmyadmin, sql-update

I have two tables:

[image: https://imgur.com/DQAXAeA]

What I needs is SQL query that I can run via the SQL tab in phpMyAdmin, which will sum the "options_stock" from "table_options" based on the "product_id", and it will write that sum number into "main_stock" in "table_products" for the corresponding "product_id", so the "table_products" will look like this:

[image: https://imgur.com/7b8NTxN]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a `join`, specifically here an `inner join`. In keeping normalization, you could keep `table_products` as a view, but you shouldn't make data dependant upon other data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below - with update join

```
update table_product p  
join 
(select product_id, sum(options_stock) as options_stock from
table_options group by product_id
) o on p.product_id=o.product_id
set main_stock=options_stock
```